# Website link that opens Instagram Direct Message with the specified href as the body text?

Tags: html, instagram, href, social-media

Basically I'm looking for Instagram's equivalent of:

`whatsapp://send?text=myspecifiedurlgoeshere.com`

I can't find anything online about this. I had no problem doing this with facebook, facebook messenger, twitter, whatsapp, and email

Answer (score 0):

There is no foolproof Instagram API for direct messages in my knowledge, let alone url param based support. And I guess there won't be any since it has been a long time.

However, you can try using the instagram-private-api to send direct messages via:

```
const userId = await ig.user.getIdByUsername('username');
const thread = ig.entity.directThread([userId.toString()]);
await thread.broadcastText('Message from node');
```

(Source: https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/issues/792)

For other software based integrations - https://maytapi.medium.com/instagram-dm-api-documentation-start-to-use-instagram-dm-api-with-4-s-84d147d7d361